Why does Jesse blame Walt for his loneliness at the hospital?
In Breaking Bad, in Season 3, aside from causing Combo's death and turning his friend into his employee, Walt doesn't do anything to cause Jesse's "loneliness," in my view.
He didn't kill Jane (Season 3 Jesse doesn't know this yet) or ruin his relationship with his parents; heck, he earns him loads of cash and saves him from Krazy-8.
Why does Jesse blame Walt for his loneliness at the hospital?
